# Phonegap (Android) app crashes immediately when i call facebook login function

Tags: cordova, facebook-android-sdk

I am creating an android app using Phonegap (Cordova v. 2.9). There is a login via facebook option in the app. So I have done setup for facebook connect plugin, but when i click on facebook login button which calls my facebookLogin() function the app crashes with a message "Unfortunetly, AppName has stopped" 
There is no facebook app installed in my emulator but it should work with browser for login, in that case if app not installed. I have implemented it few moths ago it is working fine in that app but this time I am having this trouble.
Any idea? error logs are following....

```
06-24 01:39:44.673: D/Cordova(1456): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    06-24 01:39:44.673: D/CordovaActivity(1456): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    06-24 01:39:45.563: D/dalvikvm(1456): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 338K, 11% free 3685K/4096K, paused 36ms, total 41ms
    06-24 01:39:46.133: D/CordovaLog(1456): file:///android_asset/www/js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js: Line 12 : Endpoint saved GIF89a���������������������!���������,��������������D��;
    06-24 01:39:46.133: I/chromium(1456): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Endpoint saved GIF89a
    06-24 01:39:50.663: I/Deprecation Notice(1456): Replace ctx.setActivityResultCallback() with cordova.setActivityResultCallback()
    06-24 01:39:50.663: I/Deprecation Notice(1456): Replace ctx.runOnUiThread() with cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread()
    06-24 01:39:50.703: E/ActivityThread(1456): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
    06-24 01:39:50.733: W/ResourceType(1456): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
    06-24 01:39:50.733: D/AndroidRuntime(1456): Shutting down VM
    06-24 01:39:50.733: W/dalvikvm(1456): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2accba8)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456): Process: com.android.on_me, PID: 1456
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:698)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.facebook.android.FbDialog.createCrossImage(FbDialog.java:107)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.facebook.android.FbDialog.onCreate(FbDialog.java:81)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:839)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.startDialogAuth(Facebook.java:368)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:231)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:147)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin$1.run(ConnectPlugin.java:108)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    06-24 01:39:50.753: E/AndroidRuntime(1456):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-24 01:39:52.753: I/Process(1456): Sending signal. PID: 1456 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue.
I just used the example js code for login in the github page and when i run it in emulator my app crashes the same way. Though i haven't found out the solution check below thread and it might help you.

[Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670011/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-com-facebook-katana-provider-attributionidprovi)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. I have not solved the problem, but i think this will be helpful: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started?locale=fr_FR in the "Setting a Release Key Hash" section.

`To authenticate the exchange of information between your app and the Facebook, you need to generate a release key hash and add this to the Android settings within your Facebook App ID.`